# My code does not print numbers of letters in a given text. Why?

Tags: c, cs50

I am trying to create a function as below that would count the number of letters in an inputted text and spit out an integer value. My code below compiles but it won't print out the result. Am I missing something?

```
// Libraries
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int count_letter(string text)
{
    int lettercount;
    int number_of_letters;

    number_of_letters = strlen(text);

    for(lettercount = 0; lettercount < number_of_letters;)
        if (isalpha(number_of_letters))
            lettercount++;

    return lettercount;
}

int main(void)
{
    string text = get_string("text: ");
    {
        printf("%i letter(s)", count_letter(text));
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `number_of_letters` is an int, what do you think `isalpha(number_of_letters)` evaluates to? Not to mention there are no braces `{}` surrounding the for loop or the if in the function which makes the code hard to read, and could in fact cause results you don't expect.

To be clear, this test `if (isalpha(number_of_letters))` isn't correct. Since program wants to count the number of characters in `text` that are alpha, the test would be something like `if (isalpha(text[lettercount]))`.

Comment: did what you mentioned and put the for and if loop in curly braces and changed number_of_letters to char value but it has made no difference unfortunately

Comment: clarification added to answer

Comment: got you now thanks for the clarification, its eye opening